# How can i wrap a function like <input type = "submit"> around my <a href = ""></a>

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to wrap a function like `<input type = "submit"/>` into my
`<a href="generate.php?employeeNo=< ?=$row['employeeNo']?>">`
Generate
< /a>

I tried doing this.

```
<form method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name = "payslipPeriod">
<a href="generate.php?employeeNo=<?=$row['employeeNo']?>">
<input type = "submit" value = "Generate Payslip">
</a>
</form>
$getPayslipPeriod = $_POST['payslipPeriod'];
```

But i never get the value from the form and echo it to the next page.

Comment: Make a form each employee, and have the `employeeNo` be a hidden input.

Comment: i used while statement to print the output. 
`<?php
 include 'connect.php';
 $retrive = "SELECT * FROM useremployee ORDER BY employeeNo";
 $rq = mysqli_query($connect, $retrive);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rq))
  { ?>`
`<tr>
    <td><?=$row['employeeNo']?></td>
</tr>`
`<?php
}
?>`

Is there a better way to see my database records or how can i wrap the GET method in my href and get the values in POST method to echo it on the next page?

Comment: Make a `form` for every employee. The submit button will take them to your page use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`. Use a hidden input field and give it the same name as your `GET` was so you don't need to change the index.

Answer (score 0):

This is may help:
In page 1:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['payslipPeriod'])) {
    ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href="generate.php?employeeNo=<?php echo $_POST['payslipPeriod'] ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}
?>
```

...

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
    <label for="payslipPeriod">...</label>
    <input type="text" name="payslipPeriod">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

...
Now use this in page 2:
**$_GET['employeeNo']**

Comment: i tried '
<input type = "submit" name = "Generate Payslip" value = "Generate Payslip">'

But i think it never go to the if(isset($_POST) condition.

Comment: It successfully go to the location `generate.php?employeeNo=<?=$row['employeeNo']?>`

But it didn't get the value in `<input type="text" name="payslipPeriod">`

I also tried using $_POST['...'] but it was the same.
I'm sorry but did you mean this?
$payslipPeriod = $_GET['payslipPeriod'];

Comment: Uhm, yep i did actually got the employeeNo from the start from my first code but the problem is the value in `<input type = "text" name = "payslipPeriod"> is undefined index unto the next page. What i want is upon clicking the button i can get the value from the '<input type = "text" name = "payslipPeriod">' and `generate.php?employeeNo=<?=$row['employeeNo']?>` at the same time.

Comment: I was wondering if it would be possible to use GET method into employeeNo and use POST method for my `<input name = "payrollPeriod">` to get the value from text boxes and echo it unto the next page.

Comment: Replace $row['employeeNo'] with $_POST['payslipPeriod'] in href.

Comment: I think i also need the $row['employeeNo'] at the href because in my query in the next page it's `$view = "SELECT * FROM useremployee WHERE employeeNo ='".$_GET['employeeNo']."'";` to echo the records in the database. i tried doing this         `window.location.href="generate.php?employeeNo=<?=$row['employeeNo'];$_POST['payslipPeriod']?>";` but failed. also tried the `window.location.href="generate.php?$_POST['payslipPeriod']";` but the payslipPeriod was also undefined.

Comment: Use this: window.location.href="generate.php?employeeNo=<?php $_POST['payslipPeriod'] ?>";

Comment: If i used `window.location.href="generate.php?employeeNo=<?php $_POST['payslipPeriod'] ?>` it will be employeeNo = what ever the value of the `<input type = "text" name = "payslipPeriod">` and my query will fail. Because ` $view = "SELECT * FROM useremployee WHERE employeeNo ='".$_GET['employeeNo']."'";` Tried it but didn't worked.

Comment: @Vlael Never do `WHERE employeeNo ='".$_GET['employeeNo']."`. Look up `sql injection`. The `<?php $_POST['payslipPeriod'] ?>` needs an echo but that still will fail, non of the post data will be present.

Comment: I see. Thankss for tipping the sql injection it's the first time i heared about it. So all of my database manipulation is wrong because the `sql injection` can bypass my security right? Can i have some tips for what query will i use for create, retrieve update, and delete data's on my system?

Comment: @Vlael As chris85 said, You should always validate any external inputs as you cannot trust that it will always contain what you expect. Now use this before your Query and use new variable in Query: $employeeNoData = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['employeeNo']);